# Oracle XML Gateway- Mapping XML to Oracle Apps API - Wrong Number or types of arguments mismatch error

Tags: xml, oracle, api, gateway

#### XML GATEWAY INBOUND – CALLING AN API (PL/SQL record type IN variable) TO INSERT THE DATA INTO SAMPLE TABLE

I am using XML Gateway to push data into Oracle Apps using a procedure call with “Record Type” as the parameter. I am getting a “wrong number” or types of arguments mismatch error inspite of following the process described in the Oracle XML Gateway User’s Guide

Steps followed:

1. I Created a sample table `XX_CUST_HIST(ID NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NAME VARCHAR2(50), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(50), LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(50), TITLE VARCHAR2(50))`
2. I then Created a package `XX_XML_DEMO_API` in which we have defined a record type  and   a procedure.
3. The Record type `customerRecordType`  holds account_name , first_name, last_name and the title.
4. The Procedure `insert_customer_r`  takes 2 IN arguments :

   1. p_ id  number
   2. p_customer customerRecordType
5. The procedure will insert the values into xx_cust_hist table

   ```
   p_id -> id
   p_customer.account_name -> account_name
   p_customer.first_name -> first_name
   p_customer.last_name -> last_name
   p_customer.title -> title
   ```

Now I need to call the procedure `XX_XML_DEMO_API.insert_customer_r`  from XML gateway.

Following are the steps to call the procedure:

1. Create  DTD

   ```
   ELEMENT NEW_CUSTOMER_APIR (DATAAREA)
   ELEMENT DATAAREA (CUSTOMER_DATA)
   ELEMENT CUSTOMER_DATA (ID, CUSTOMER_RECORD)
   ELEMENT ID (#PCDATA)
   ELEMENT CUSTOMER_RECORD (ACCOUNT_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TITLE)
   ELEMENT ACCOUNT_NAME    (#PCDATA)
   ELEMENT FIRST_NAME (#PCDATA)
   ELEMENT LAST_NAME (#PCDATA)
   ELEMENT TITLE (#PCDATA)
   ```
2. Creation of XML map
   Data Definition type for Source and Destination are set to XML.

   While executing the procedure `XX_XML_DEMO_API.insert_customer_r` in post_process from the message designer, instead of 2 `(p_id IN   number , p_customer IN customerRecordType)` parameters it is showing  6 parameters `(p_id IN number, p_customer IN customerRecordType, account_name IN varchar2, first_name IN varchar2, last_name IN varchar2, title IN varchar2)`. Six parameters are getting mapped, instead of the 2 that the procedure really needs.
3. Testing of XML map.
   Error message in transaction monitor:

   ```
   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in
   call to 'INSERT_CUSTOMER_R' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
   PL/SQL: Statement ignored -           ECX_ACTIONS.BIND_PROC_VARIABLES
   ```

The process executed and produced the error message given in the step 3.
The standard documentation is unclear on how this should be done.
Being a newbie to the XML Gateway technology I am unable to get a clue about what the error message could be and which step of the process produced the message. Could anyone help me to proceed further?

Thanks in advance.